# Intent filter for email attachments

Tags: android, android-intent, email-attachments, intentfilter

I want to open audio attachments in emails with my app. Currently my intent filter is like so:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <data android:mimeType="audio/wav" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.wav"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.wav"/>
        <data android:scheme="content" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.wav"/>
        <data android:scheme="file" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.wav"/>
</intent-filter>
```

This works for everything I want it to except for email attachments. Currently if I'm sent a wav file, the only thing I can do is preview it, and that opens with Winamp (so clearly 3rd party apps have a way in). I can't find what I should be adding to do this though, does anyone have any idea?

**Edit**

Here's what LogCat has to say on the matter. When I click Preview I get

```
01-10 19:28:52.691: INFO/ActivityManager(109): Starting: Intent { dat=content://gmail-ls/messages/xxxxxxx%40gmail.com/439/attachments/0.1/BEST/false cmp=com.google.android.gm/.ViewAttachmentActivity } from pid 19483
```

What's bizarre is that Winamp automatically opens, and is not set as default. I'm given no choice...

Comment: the only thing i know for sure is that attachments content provider doesn't use filename but some alphanumeric code, so the *.wav filter doesn't work for that. mimetype should be used instead.

Comment: I've already got `<data android:mimeType="audio/wav" />` in there, is there another way I should be doing it?

Comment: don't know... i had this `<data android:scheme="content" android:mimeType="text/xml"/>` for xml and it worked. (category=default, action=view)

Comment: Still no luck, the only button for the attachment is 'Preview' and it still goes straight to Winamp.

Comment: Why didn't you try **android:host="gmail-ls"**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

email clients seem to choose mimetypes for attachments in an arbitrary way, so intent filters to open them must contemplate all possibilities. searching the internet helps to find all the possible types and one should add a `<data/>` filter for each of them, if a wildcard like `audio/*` is not desired (as [OP says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649969/intent-filter-for-email-attachments/4651022#4651022)).

anyway, filtering by mimetype is suggested as a first choice other than filtering by filename extension (see [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg47417.html) on android-dev ml).

(thanks fredley)

Comment: Why not just use **android:mimeType="\*/\*"**

Answer (score 2):

Replacing `audio/wav` with `audio/*` makes it work, however this is obviously undesirable behaviour.

Comment: what is the actual mimetype in the email? i know it depends on the client, maybe it doesn't set it as `audio/wav` but something else like `audio/x-wav`?

Comment: it is `audio/x-wav`, thanks for your help. Write it as an answer so that I can accept it!